# SQL Injection: or 1=1 vs ' or 1=1; -- -

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Trying to learn and understand SQL injection.

Can anyone explain to me why `' or 1=1; --` - allowed me to bypass authentication and `or 1=1` did not?

Comment: Start with this query: `SELECT 1 as Authenticated WHEN Password='$password' AND Username='dr98'` Now, replace $password with each of the values, verbatim. What is the difference in the resulting string-to-be-run-as-a-query?

Comment: Because `WHERE USername = 'MyUserName' AND PasswordHash = 'dsiahbgfdfohgbsdfjobghsl' OR 1=1` is true, and therefore you authenticated. This is why you never inject, and ***always*** parametrise.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you interested in? You have tagged 3!

Comment: `; --`, semi-colon terminates the statement, and `--` comments out the rest of the query. Need to see the full query to be sure why that works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Think of a query that is built using string concatenation:

```
"select * from myTable where id = '" + txtIdEnteredByUser +"'"
```

If the end user inputs:

```
' or 1=1; --
```

then the query becomes:

```
select * from myTable where id = '' or 1=1; --'
```

That is a valid query and always evaluates to true because of the (OR 1=1), as a result the whole table values are returned.

However, if the user input was:

```
or 1=1;
```

the query becomes:

```
select * from myTable where id = ' or 1=1;'
```

which is query that wouldn't return something (likely).